# ImageView not display an image when taking a picture from the gallery Android Apps

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have some problem with imageview in my android apps, I want to crop the image into round after i take picture from camera or get image from gallery. when i'm going with take picture from camera, that's function is normally, but if i'm go with get the image from gallery i got some error where not showing in logcat.

here my code :

this code to call the option menu to take picture or get from gallery :

```
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityRegister.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                //define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera activity
                String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
                //create parameters for Intent with filename
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera");
                //imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                //create new Intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", -1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", -1);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);

                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_Camera_IMAGE);
            }else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")){
                try{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    intent.putExtra("aspectX", -1);
                    intent.putExtra("aspectY", -1);
                    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

crop to round the image :

```
public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 300, 300, false);
    return _bmp;
}
```

and this code to decode image from camera or gallery

```
public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }
    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    ivImages.setImageBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(bitmap));
}
```

this my onActivityResult() Code :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    String filePath = null;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
                if(extra != null) {
                    selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                }
            }
            break;
        case PICK_Camera_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //use imageUri here to access the image
                selectedImageUri = imageUri;
                /*
                Bitmap mPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mPic, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())));
                */
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }

    if(selectedImageUri != null){
        try {
            // OI FILE Manager
            String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
            // MEDIA GALLERY
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                filePath = selectedImagePath;
            } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                filePath = filemanagerstring;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
            }

            if (filePath != null) {
                decodeFile(filePath);
            } else {
                bitmap = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Have you overrided ONActivityResult()?

Comment: Share your onActivityResult() code.

Comment: I did not put override in onActivityResult(). @Jois

Comment: I've added onActivityResult ( ) code @AKSiddique

Comment: share your onActivityResutlt() code

Comment: I've been added on bottom of post @Jois

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. To get the image do it this way. this worked for me

if your trying to set the imageView to this selected image then the code goes like this.

**Activity class**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();





        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
              imageView.setImageBitmap(ProfilePicture.getRoundedRectBitmap(resized));



    }


}
```

ImageConvertor Class

```
public class ProfilePicture {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap() {
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

            int color = 0xff424242;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);



        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

this line `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);` helps you to get the selected image from the gallery with help of ContentResolver.

I hope this was helpful. Thnakyou

Comment: thank's for your help @Jois, and i got that solved. Thank's

Comment: i have edited my code. i have added a new class called profilePicture. use it in your code actually it's simple. I hope this was helpful

Comment: hey if u got it right then dont forget to vote and tick the answer! ThankYou :D